# react/redux: todos example what {...todo} work for poprs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning redux follow redux tutorial,when I saw `todos` [todos-github](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos) example something confuse me:
Todo.js

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text}) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
)
```

TodoList.js

```
const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {
      todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo} //how does it work?
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)
```

`todos` is an array ,`todo` is an object:

[image]

`Todo` item's props:

[image]

As I know now,the `Todo`,`TodoList` component function pass on params by using `ES6  Destructuring assignment` , but how `{...todo}` work ? it must do something to `props`, the `{}` in this is stand for it's a `javascript syntax` ,so `...todo` is a `Varargs` to `Todo` component function? I dont know, any help appreciate.

Comment: That is a spread operator syntax. See the duplicate question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check what `{...todos}` compiles to using [Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=const%20Todo%20%3D%20(%7B%20onClick%2C%20completed%2C%20text%7D)%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%3Cli%0A%20%20%20%20onClick%3D%7BonClick%7D%0A%20%20%20%20style%3D%7B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20textDecoration%3A%20completed%20%3F%20'line-through'%20%3A%20'none'%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%7D%0A%20%20%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7Btext%7D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fli%3E%0A)%0A%0Aconst%20todos%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%20completed%3A%20false%2C%20id%3A%200%2C%20text%3A%20%22test1%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20completed%3A%20false%2C%20id%3A%201%2C%20text%3A%20%22test2%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20completed%3A%20false%2C%20id%3A%202%2C%20text%3A%20%22test3%22%20%7D%2C%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20inner%20%3D%20todos.map(todo%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%3CTodo%20key%3D%7Btodo.id%7D%20%7B...todo%7D%20%2F%3E%0A)).

As you can see in the link above (I removed some stuff for clarity, but it should be simple enough) the part where the `Todo` component is created and `{...todo}` is passed as a prop gets compiled to:

```js
React.createElement(Todo, _extends({ key: todo.id }, todo));
```

(The `onClick` prop has been omitted for simplicity - were it included, you would see `_extends({ key: todo.id, onClick: /* onClick function */ }, todo)`

So the `{...todo}` prop actually causes Babel to generate this `_extends` function, which is defined as:

```js
var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { 
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
    var source = arguments[i]; 
    for (var key in source) { 
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { 
        target[key] = source[key]; 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  return target; 
};
```

(The code above is generated as a one-liner by Babel - I cleaned it up for legibility)

So, as you can see, passing a prop using destructuring assignment into a React component causes all the properties of the destructured object to be copied into the props object passed to the component on creation. This behavior is not a standardized ES6 feature - instead, it is a part of JSX syntax.

In summary: If your `todo` object looks like:

```js
{ completed: false, id: 0, text: "test1" }
```

Passing `{...todo}` as a prop is the equivalent of passing

```js
completed={false} id={0} text="test1"
```

as props, and you can do this because it is a feature of the JSX specification.

Comment: when I saw the code ,I know what it do! thanks!